# What's wrong with vCard=$(echo $REPLY | cut -d'i' -f 1)

Tags: linux, bash, shell

when I test the code below, I got an error said :

```
syntax error near unexpected token `)'
```

Here is the code:

```
oVideos=$Videos
Videos="Please select a video card: "
select myvideo in "Intel" \
        "Intel i915" \
        "Intel i965" \
        "NVIDIA" \
        "AMD" \
        "ATI" \
        "Radeon"
do
    if [ "$REPLY" == "quit" ]; then
        echo "OK, see you! Have a great one!"
        exit
    fi

    if [ ! -z "$myvideo" ]; then
        case $REPLY in 
            1) if [ checkVideoCard $REPLY == 0 ]; then
                echo "VIDEO_CARDS=\"intel\"" >> $MAKECONF
               fi

            2) vCard=$(echo $REPLY | cut -d'i' -f 1)
               if [ checkVideoCard $REPLY  == 0 ]; then
                echo "VIDEO_CARDS=\"intel i915\"" >> $MAKECONF
               fi
        esac
     fi
done
```

...

checkVideoCard is a function which aims to match user's selection and lspci result. Don't worry about it.

Thank you very much!

Comment: You are missing the `;;` to end the `1)` block.

Comment: Among other errors. `if [ checkVideoCard $REPLY == 0 ]; then` is going to throw an error also.

Comment: Run your code through http://www.shellcheck.net it'll help.

Comment: Among other things, `$REPLY` should almost certainly be `"$REPLY"`. It probably doesn't make any direct difference in this case, but it's a good habit.

Comment: Yes, Etan, even if I separate it to myresult=checkVideoCard "$REPLY" , it throws an error command not found, Why?

Comment: @TaoWang, because that's running `$REPLY` as a command with `myresult` set as an environment variable with the value `checkVideoCard`.

Comment: @TaoWang, ...and *of course* it's too many arguments; running `[ test something ]` is the same as running `test test something`, as `[` is an alternate name for `test`.

Comment: Rolled back to revision 2 because editing an answered question to add more questions to it is against site rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must terminate the commands associated with a particular case value with `;;`:

```
case $REPLY in 
    1) if [ "$(checkVideoCard "$REPLY")" = 0 ]; then
           echo "VIDEO_CARDS=\"intel\"" >> $MAKECONF
       fi
       ;;
    # Because there's no difference among intel video cards, so please make sure what exact video card type you have.
    2) vCard=$(echo $REPLY | cut -d'i' -f 1)
       if [ "$(checkVideoCard "$REPLY")"  = 0 ]; then
           echo "VIDEO_CARDS=\"intel i915\"" >> $MAKECONF
       fi
       ;;
esac
```

It's not the assignment that's the problem, it's the attempt to start a new case with `2)` while the previous one is unterminated.

Comment: You should probably mention (and fix) the non-calls to `checkVideoCard` in those tests too and also suggest using an exit code instead of standard output (assuming that's what was supposed to be being done there).

Comment: ./test: line 107: [: too many arguments. It's the result returned from if. line 107 is : 1) if [ ... ]; then

Comment: Sorry, line 107 is not what I wrote, it's in the function.

Comment: I updated the question, would you please take a look, chepner?

Comment: @TaoWang, updating a question (particularly an answered one) to add more questions is not kosher. This question was already arguably too broad already when asked and in need of MCVE treatment (see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve); the new question should get that treatment as well, and be asked separately.